Does LISN eliminate differential mode noise?
Do I understand correctly that this LISN circuit doesn't eliminate differential mode noise? And when I get a spectrum, there are two parts of noise: differential mode (DM) and common mode (CM)?


Can I ask what is LISN?  EUT?

Eliminate it from what, or going where? Please specify.

FYI: According to the site rules on citations and references you have to post the source of your diagram

LISN: Line Impedance Stabalisation Network.  Dave Smith did a good explanation on EEVBlog.  EUT:  Equipment Under Test.

The two uncoupled 50uH inductors taken together will block both CM and DM signals.
it looks like the moitoring switches are set-up to give readings for the individual copnductors. not combineed DM and CM
getting good DM and CM readings would probably require adding a transformer to the LISN

Block what, or where?

Rf signals from traveling between left and right sides.
